# Google Forms permissions

Tags: google-account, google-forms

I joined for a FitBit Zoom Webinar and then takes you for a Google Forms survey and when I leave Zoom to go Google Forms. I need Permissions. Any Suggestions on how to work this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The owner of this form chose ["Restrict to your organization’s users"](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9302966#2.1). You either have to be a (signed in) employee or ask the owner to disable this setting.